# CUDAQ[ ] returns False after update

Tags: cudalink

When I try

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAQ[]
```

It returns

> `False`

I tried `CUDAResourceUninstall` and `Install` as well as to update.

```
CUDADriverVersion[]
```

returns

> `390.48.0`

`CUDAResourceInformation` returns:

> ```
> {{"Name" -> "CUDAResources", "Version" -> "11.3.154", 
>   "BuildNumber" -> "", "Qualifier" -> "Lin64", 
>   "WolframVersion" -> "11.3", "SystemID" -> {"Linux-x86-64"}, 
>   "Description" -> "{ToolkitVersion -> v9.1, MinimumDriver -> 290}", 
>   "Category" -> "", "Creator" -> "", "Publisher" -> "", 
>   "Support" -> "", "Internal" -> False, 
>   "Location" -> 
>      "/home/markus/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/CUDAResources-Lin64-11.3.154", 
>   "Context" -> {}, "Enabled" -> True, "Loading" -> Manual, 
>   "Hash" -> "2bcd82c65870e597344b0444ebbc5c27"}}
> ```

Also:

```
GPUTools`Internal`$NVIDIADriver
```

gives

> `"/usr/lib/nvidia-390/libnvidia-tls.so.390.48"`

and

```
GPUTools`Internal`$CUDALibraryPath
```

gives

> `"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so"`

Comment: What is the GPU model?

Comment: If your GPU is based off of the Tesla or Fermi architecture it will not work with CUDA Toolkit 9.1, which is used in M11.3

Comment: What about Quadro K2200 card? Can one use the newer CUDA Toolkit (version 10) from NVIDIA with M11.3?

Answer (score 0):

Needs to create a library link to the NVIDIA driver, e.g. if the driver version is 440.44 then:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libnvidia-tls.so.440.44 /usr/lib64/libnvidia-tls.so.1
```

and restart MMA.